# Selenium grid keeps session alive after test has been completed and browser closed

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid2

I am new to automated testing and selenium grid. I have been able to start my hub and create nodes in which I run my tests, but, I am hitting a wall here. After I run a test and the browser closes it keeps the session open thus making my next test fail and the session is kept alive for a long time when I look at the available instances in the hub's console. How can I make the session end and release the browser instance for subsequent tests?

Comment: What browser are you using in this use case?  That might be a critical piece of information to answer your question.   If your using Chrome or IE, what version of the binary driver did you register to the grid?

Comment: I am using chrome and firefox. I was able to solve the problem by using driver.Dipose()

Comment: Sounds like your using either the Ruby bindings or the C# bindings?

Answer (score 3):

The simplest issue would be that you are using `driver.close()` which only closes the browser window and not the driver itself. You would need to use `driver.quit()`. If this is not the issue it would be easier to troubleshoot if we knew what WebDriver bindings you are using in your tests.

Comment: Yes sonhu, that was the issue, now I changed it to driver.Dispose() and that solved the problem. Thanks